# is it possible to use tomcat 10 for JEE and tomcat 9 for spring on one laptop?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

is it possible to use tomcat 10 for JEE and tomcat 9 for spring on one laptop? if yes can you ask for instructions on how to do this

Comment: I don't know why this should not be possible. It should be enough to adjust the ports, so that there's no collision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just create two projects and connected to both with two different tomcat versions, you can even change the port of the server. But remember both will not run together if they have the same port.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run both server on one computer as long as they are running on different ports

For JEE application to change port you can click on server tab and double click on Apache version and change the port from there. You can see detailed information in the below link:
https://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse

And for spring you can edit application.properties file and set server.port=9090 or anything, this will change the port

By default for both port is 8080, so changing in one of them will make you running both server on a single laptop